# If $Y$ is a function of $X$, is it possible the two variables are independent?

Tags: statistics, independence, covariance

If I have a variable $X$ and a variable $Y$ where $Y = \alpha + \beta + X$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants is there any scenario in which $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Intuitively, I feel the answer is no, meaning Cov($X$,$Y$) $\ne$ $0$, but I want to be sure.

Comment: The only possibility is that $Y$ is almost constant: each event $[Y \le y]$ should be independent of itself, so it must have probability 0 or 1.

Comment: Given $f$ Borel, we have that $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent if and only if $f(X)$ is constant a.e.. This is because for all $\alpha$, we must have $$0=P[X\in f^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)\land f(X)\le \alpha]=P[f(X)>\alpha]P[f(X)\le \alpha]=\\=(1-P[f(X)\le \alpha])P[f(X)\le\alpha]$$ Therefore, for all $\alpha$, either $P[f(X)\le\alpha]=1$ or $P[f(X)\le\alpha]=0$. It's quite clear that this implies that $f(X)=\inf\{\alpha\in\Bbb R\,:\, P[f(X)\le \alpha]=1\}$ a.e.. The other implication is obvious.

Comment: Incidentally, here $X$ and $Y$ are also correlated (unless they are independent), because $\operatorname{Cov}(X,k+X)=\operatorname{Cov}(X,X)=\operatorname{Var}(X)$

Comment: Let $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are the sample mean and variance of normal sample of size $n,$ then one can show (Basu) that $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are stochastically independent. However, there is a sense in which $S^2$ is a function of $\bar X$ because $(n-1)S^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2.$ // Independence of $\bar X$ and $S^2$ is true only for normal data. // For exponential data correlation positive; for BETA(.2, .2) data, correlation = 0 by symmetry, but plot of $\bar X$ vs $S^2$ shows obvious dependence.

Comment: See [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350571/for-non-negative-data-the-sample-mean-is-not-smaller-than-its-standard-error/1351904#1351904)/